# Sorting local storage (array/stringify)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, local-storage

I have user inputs (Worker's name, Car Vin, Start time and End time) being display underneath the form after storing in the local storage. I want to sort the employees' name in alphabetical order. Where do i place the code and how would i write the code.

```
// Car Class: Represent a Car
class Car{
  constructor(worker, carVin, strTime, endTime){
        this.worker = worker;
        this.carVin = carVin;
        this.strTime = strTime; 
        this.endTime = endTime; 
    }
 }
```

// UI Class: Handle UI Tasks

```
 class UI {
    static displayCars(){
      const cars = Store.getCars();

      cars.forEach((car) => UI.addCarToList(car));
  }
    static addCarToList(car){
      const list = document.querySelector('#car-list');

      const row = document.createElement('tr');

      row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${car.worker}</td>
      <td>${car.carVin}</td>
      <td>${car.strTime}</td>
      <td>${car.endTime}</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm 
      delete">Clear</a></td>`;

      list.appendChild(row);
  }
  static deleteCar(el){
      if(el.classList.contains('delete')){
          el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      }
  }
  static showAlert(message, className){
      const div =document.createElement('div');
      div.className = `alert alert-${className}`;
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
      const container = document.querySelector('.container');
      const form = document.querySelector('#car-form');
      container.insertBefore(div, form);

      // Vanish in 3 secs
      setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.alert').remove(),3000);
  }

  static clearFields(){
      document.querySelector('#worker').value = '';
      document.querySelector('#carVin').value = '';
      document.querySelector('#strTime').value = '';
      document.querySelector('#endTime').value = '';
   }

}
```

// Store Class: Handle Storage

```
  class Store{
   static getCars(){
     let cars;
     if(localStorage.getItem('cars') === null){
         cars = [];
      } else {
         cars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cars'));
     }

      return cars;
    }
    static addCar(car){
       const cars = Store.getCars();
       cars.push(car);
     // using JSON to convert array to string
       localStorage.setItem('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
    }
  // carvin unique for each car
    static removeCars(carVin){
       const cars = Store.getCars();

       cars.forEach((car, index) => {
         if(car.carVin === carVin) {
             cars.splice(index, 1);
          }
       });
        localStorage.setItem('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
    }
 }
```

// Event: Display Cars:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayCars);
 //Event: Add a  Car:
 document.querySelector('#car-form').addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
// Prevent actual submit
 e.preventDefault();

// Get form Value
const worker = document.querySelector('#worker').value;
const carVin = document.querySelector('#carVin').value;
const strTime = document.querySelector('#strTime').value;
const endTime = document.querySelector('#endTime').value;

//Validate
if(worker === ''|| carVin === ''|| strTime === '' || endTime === ''){
    UI.showAlert('Please fill all fields', 'danger');   
} else {

    //Instatiate book
    const car = new Car(worker, carVin, strTime, endTime);

    // Add book to list 
    UI.addCarToList(car);

    // Add book to local storage
    Store.addCar(car);

    // Show Success msg
    UI.showAlert('Car Added', 'success');

    //Clear fields
    UI.clearFields();

}
```

});

//Event: Remove a Car
....some code...

Comment: You have two options. Either (1) get the contents of the local storage before you add a new entry (e.g. at the `Store.addCar(car)` line ), add the new entry, and do a sorting at that point and then update the local storage, or (2) better yet leave the contents of local storage unsorted and move the sorting logic in the place where this data is actually being displayed or used.

Comment: You will probably place the sorting code in the addCar() method.

Comment: I want to be able to see both results first the user entries THEN sortedCars on another form with its own button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
// Car Class: Represent a Car
class Car{
  constructor(worker, carVin, strTime, endTime){
        this.worker = worker;
        this.carVin = carVin;
        this.strTime = strTime; 
        this.endTime = endTime; 
    }
 }

class UI {
    static displayCars(){
      const cars = Store.getCars();
      const list = document.querySelector('#car-list'); ///
      list.innerHTML = ""; ///
      cars.forEach((car) => UI.addCarToList(car));
  }
    static addCarToList(car){
      const list = document.querySelector('#car-list');
      const row = document.createElement('tr');
      row.innerHTML = `
      <td>${car.worker}</td>
      <td>${car.carVin}</td>
      <td>${car.strTime}</td>
      <td>${car.endTime}</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm 
      delete">Clear</a></td>`;
      list.appendChild(row);
  }
  static deleteCar(el){
      if(el.classList.contains('delete')){
          el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      }
  }
  static showAlert(message, className){
      const div =document.createElement('div');
      div.className = `alert alert-${className}`;
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
      const container = document.querySelector('.container');
      const form = document.querySelector('#car-form');
      container.insertBefore(div, form);

      // Vanish in 3 secs
      setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('.alert').remove(),3000);
  }

  static clearFields(){
      document.querySelector('#worker').value = '';
      document.querySelector('#carVin').value = '';
      document.querySelector('#strTime').value = '';
      document.querySelector('#endTime').value = '';
   }

}

class Store{
   static getCars(){
     let cars;
     if(localStorage.getItem('cars') === null){
         cars = [];
      } else {
         cars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cars'));
     }

      return cars;
    }
    static addCar(car){
       const cars = Store.getCars();
       cars.push(car);
       cars.sort((a,b)=> ( a.worker < b.worker ) ? -1 : ( a.worker > b.worker ) ? 1 : 0 ); ///
       localStorage.setItem('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
    }
  // carvin unique for each car
    static removeCars(carVin){
       const cars = Store.getCars();

       cars.forEach((car, index) => {
         if(car.carVin === carVin) {
             cars.splice(index, 1);
          }
       });
        localStorage.setItem('cars', JSON.stringify(cars));
    }
 }

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayCars);
 //Event: Add a  Car:
 document.querySelector('#car-form').addEventListener('submit',(e) => {
// Prevent actual submit
 e.preventDefault();

// Get form Value
const worker = document.querySelector('#worker').value;
const carVin = document.querySelector('#carVin').value;
const strTime = document.querySelector('#strTime').value;
const endTime = document.querySelector('#endTime').value;

//Validate
if(worker === ''|| carVin === ''|| strTime === '' || endTime === ''){
    UI.showAlert('Please fill all fields', 'danger');   
} else {

    //Instatiate book
    const car = new Car(worker, carVin, strTime, endTime);

    // Add book to list 
    // UI.addCarToList(car); ///

    // Add book to local storage
    Store.addCar(car);
    UI.displayCars(); ///

    // Show Success msg
    UI.showAlert('Car Added', 'success');

    //Clear fields
    UI.clearFields();

}
});
```

Test, and let me know if this is close to what you want to achieve.

(My additions have a /// at the right side)

Comment: Yes it is, all the entries are being sorted before displayed using the same initial button. THANK YOU